# Proving OAuth authentication to third party

Tags: authentication, oauth, google-oauth, facebook-oauth

Probably a long shot, but after authenticating a user via OAuth and retrieving some user info from the provider,  is there a way to prove to a third party that this user is authenticated and that this piece of information retrieved with the token (an email address, for example) is indeed the data supplied by that provider? Without sharing the access token, of course.

Primarily interested in Google and Facebook here, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

The general, standard way is to use [OAuth2 Introspection](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7662).

Not everyone supports this (I don't know of any of your 3 providers do). Potentially a good fallback could be to just do a request and see if it succeeds.